# Ansible error on start Confluence service

Tags: linux, ansible, devops

Trying to do automate installation of Confluence service and when it comes up to systemd/service start - it brokes with no visible error.

```
fatal: [VM_Name]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to start service confluence.service: Job for confluence.service failed because the control process exited with error code.\nSee \"systemctl status confluence.service\" and \"journalctl -xeu confluence.service\" for details.\n"}
```

Turns out if I do it myself afterwards - it will start working. Or I can do double time the same command and with one failure second will start the service. It's a workaround but can it be done with one step?

Quick note: `systemctl status confluence.service` and `journalctl -xeu confluence.service` just saying that service tried to start and failed after a few milliseconds.

UPD: on first startup it says: "Existing PID file found during start. Tomcat appears to still be running with PID ***. Start aborted." - and than it showing same PID from confluence user starting confluence.service.

Quick note 2: `become: true` is on whole playbook.

Quick note 3: I have confluence.service in /usr/lib/systemd/system (doing this thing on Rocky Linux 9).

Ansible playbook commands:

```
- name: Confluence | Start and enabled
  service:
    name: confluence.service
    state: restarted
    enabled: yes
```

or

```
- name: Confluence | Start and enabled
  systemd:
    name: confluence.service
    state: restarted
    daemon_reload: true
    enabled: yes
```

None of them works if it's done once.

Comment: Ansible is telling you that the systemd service failed to start, and the error message includes some suggested diagnostic steps. Did you perform them? What was the output?

Comment: @larsks blind me. Didn't notice after restart in ```systemctl status confluence.service``` that it says that Tomcat is still running. After first start it sends error and after second it just rewrites it. But how can I rid of it if I'm trying to do clean install after deleting confluence from system? Seems there is no "Tomcat"/"java" or whatsoever in ```ps aux``` command.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution myself.

Before starting a service just deleted a catalina.pid in /opt/atlassian/confluence/work

Now it works.